# Why does the make function not return a pointer?

Tags: go

I am new to Go, but my understanding is that assignments create copies. The "new" function returns a pointer, which makes sense because then when you assign the return value to a variable, it will only copy the pointer. However, since "make" does not return a pointer, will the newly allocated object not be copied when assigning it to a variable, resulting in a second allocation for the copy?

```
variable := make([]int, 4, 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

`[]int` is a slice, not an array; and slices are [basically pointer views into an underlying array](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Slice_types):

> A slice is a descriptor for a contiguous segment of an *underlying array* and provides access to a numbered sequence of elements from that array.

Your `make` line (a) instantiates a `[7]int` which you never see, and then (b) returns a slice that is essentially just a pointer into the first 4 elements into that array. Since that slice is just a pointer and a length, it is cheap to pass by value. I'm not sure if Go actually creates the slice "internally" to `make` and then returns it to your `variable`, or whether it inlines that directly; but the effect either way would be negligible.

From the docs:

> That is, executing
>
> ```
> make([]T, length, capacity)
> ```
>
> produces the same slice as allocating an array and slicing it, so these two expressions are equivalent:
>
> ```
> make([]int, 50, 100)
> new([100]int)[0:50]
> ```

Comment: Yes, and a map is a little bit more complicated but it's still basically just a pointer to the bucket array (the actual contents) plus some housekeeping data.